# mostrar color de acuerdo a valor en la base de datos

Tags: php, pdo

hola amigos estoy mostrando el status de una consulta y le añado un color en especifico pero lo noto como muy antiguo, ese tipo de modelo y quisiera mostrarlo un poco diferente el modelo antiguo es el ejemplo con el color azul y como quisiera mostrarlo es el ejemplo con el color amarillo:

**aquí mi consulta:**

```
<?php

  class crud
 {
private $db;

function __construct($DB_con)
{
    $this->db = $DB_con;
}


/* paging */

public function dataview($query)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
    {
        while($linea=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {


        $status_color = array(
                    'Pendiente' => '#b71c1c',
                    'Procesando' => '#1565c0',
                    'Procesado' => '#fbc02d'
                          );

            echo "<tr>
            <td>$linea[nombres])</td>
            <td>$linea[apellidos]</td>
            <td>$linea[totalpago]</td>            
            <td align=center class='center-align white-text' 
            bgcolor='". $status_color[$linea['status']] ."'>$linea[status]
         </td>";

          ?>
```

**el div que utilizo para mostrarlo de una forma diferente a la actual**

```
  `echo "<td align=center><div class='col s10 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'><p class='black-text'>$linea[status]</h5></div></p>";`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Disculpa, no veo tu problema , podrías ser un poquito mas especifico, porque desde lo que veo, solo tendrias que reemplazar la class css "yellow " por la variable $status_color[$linea['status']] y dicha variable almacenaría la class css del color que quieres

Comment: me explico ella funciona bien pero lo que quiero es mostrarla a la imagen con el div amarrillo, porque como lo estoy mastranto actualmente se me llena toda la casilla y no me gusta así se ve mas bonito con el div

Comment: Pregunta, esto te funciona como quieres? <td align=center><div class='col s10 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'><p class='black-text'>$linea[status]</h5></div></p>

Comment: sigue sin ser claro cuál es el problema, ¿qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: si @Andres perfectamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu Código seria el siguiente:

```
<?php

  class crud
 {
private $db;

function __construct($DB_con)
{
    $this->db = $DB_con;
}


/* paging */

public function dataview($query)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
    {
        while($linea=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {


        $status_color = array(
                    'Pendiente' => '#b71c1c', /*<-- En vez de color pones el nombre de la clase*/
                    'Procesando' => 'yellow',
                    'Procesado' => '#fbc02d'/*<-- En vez de color pones el nombre de la clase*/
                          );

            echo "<tr>
            <td>$linea[nombres])</td>
            <td>$linea[apellidos]</td>
            <td>$linea[totalpago]</td>            
            <td align=center><div class='col s10 card-panel '". $status_color[$linea['status']] ."' darken-2 center'><p class='black-text'>$linea[status]</p></div></td>";

          ?>
```

Comment: gracias ahora si me sirve perfectamente, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, Estamos para ayudar